# Bluetooth Apple Keyboard connects but unresponsive

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, apple, 14.04

So I upgraded to 14.04 today, and once everything was installed i noticed that my apple bluetooth keyboard stopped working. It was working fine in 12.04.

The keyboard pairs and connects fine, and I have noticed that every time I press a button on the keyboard the bluetooth icon has a little lock next to it. But once i stop typing the lock goes away. Is there some sort of keyboard lock i am unaware of?

Hope to get this resolved soon

thanks again